# Adding element between two other elements in a double linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm writing a programm in java and for that need I need to implement an element between two other elements in a linked list, since i'm sorting.

I have time issues, so I'll stop on the idea of using a Compareable Interface or something similar.

My Question is rather simple, but Google Search didn't throw any helpful advice my way.

add and addLast are command lines i know for lists, but how can I add them between two elements and i'm sure it works, how would an example code look like?

Comment: If you look at the methods, you also have an `add` method with an index, so you just have to specify at which index you want to add your element.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28int,%20E%29

Comment: Lets say i have a size of 2 elements in my linkedlist.
I'll name them c and c+1, how would i add them between with the index? Can i just say list.add(c+1) and he moves the reference on his own?

Comment: If you have a `LinkedList` called `list` with already 2 elements, and you wanted to add an `Element E` between them, you would do: `list.add(1, E);`. The second element of the list would automatically shift to the third place.

Comment: Alright.. seems reasonable, i think i'll work it out. It seems to work to some extent and i think there might be a problem in my code, but at least i got a direction now. thank you.